# Is setting a components defaultProps to null bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-proptypes

So my company, like many have adopted Airbnb's linting rules which require me to set `propTypes` and `defaultProps` in my react components.

As far as I'm aware, my redux store is handling this for me in its `initialState`.  I can set my `propTypes` easily enough, but it kicks off when I don't have corresponding `defaultProps`, looking online and through a few posts here it seems "okay"? to set them to `null` or `undefined`.  The code below works as I'd expect it to, but something doesn't sit right with me in setting them all to `null`?  In my real world code I've got a list of 15 things all set like this and I'm not sold on it being okay...

Is there a proper or better way to achieve this?  Thanks a lot!

**Full example of my code:** https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-ishizaka-pv2ix

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { someAction } from "./actions";

const propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  buttonText: PropTypes.string,
  someAction: PropTypes.func
};

const defaultProps = {
  title: null,
  buttonText: null,
  someAction: null
};

const Component = ({ ...props }) => {
  const { title, buttonText, someAction } = props;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={someAction}>
        {buttonText}
      </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

Component.propTypes = propTypes;
Component.defaultProps = defaultProps;

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  title: state.title,
  buttonText: state.buttonText
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  someAction: () => dispatch(someAction())
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Component);
```

Comment: It's better than them being `undefined` and crashing the app, I suppose, but it's unclear why a component that's using redux would not have the props populated by the reducer 100% of the time, unless they are local state

Comment: @MarkC. In the components this concerns, the props are 100% at the reducers mercy, there are no "default props".  But as part of a larger workspace, the linting rules weren't happy with me not declaring propTypes or defaultProps.  My code example works as I would expect it to...  But having an object full of null values seems really strange to me!

Comment: Unless you have a better default value in mind or you can make these props required, `null` is fine and common for any optional prop.

Comment: Thanks @EmileBergeron - I guess it just seems really weird having nothing but a list of null values!  I appreciate that!